# How to generate a text webpage after uploading an xlsx file in Django?

Tags: python, django, excel

I have a field where users upload an xlsx file In Django, however, im having trouble getting Django to return a simple text-based webpage from users uploading that xlsx file. Basically, I need Django to generate text from the cells of the xlsx file they uploaded. Im trying to use openpyxl to do this. How do I get Django to generate a new page with the results of the xlsx file after my script runs over it? Do I need to create a new template that redirects to it once the user submits the uploaded xlsx file? Here's an example.

```
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from .forms import UploadForm
import openpyxl

def index2(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = UploadForm()
    else:
        form = UploadForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            file = request.FILES['fileobj']
            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
            sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
            # script that runs overs the sheet here...
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('webpage with results'))


    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'upload/upload_page.html', context)
```

Comment: It seems like you're on the right track to a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest decompose the problem. Right now you're trying to solve several things at once:

1. Upload the file
2. Save the file
3. Parse the file
4. Render a view of the file

I'd put 1) and 2) to the side and work on the XSLX loading/viewing part independently. For example, you could hard-code the path of the file in the view and get it rock solid that way. It's just development after all. Once it's good, remove the hard-coded file and connect up the real upload/save logic.

Realistically, you'll want to create a model class that represents say `UploadedExcelFile`. When the file is uploaded, create an instance and save it (i.e. a row in the database). Then you write a view that loads that model instance, which in turn can load the Excel file.

You might also want to consider ingesting the file rather than just storing on disk, or using some kind of async approach (e.g. [django-q](http://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)). This depends on a few factors, like what kind of information needs to be extracted from the file, is it editable etc. If it were me, and not knowing the bounds of your system, I'd do something like this:

- Upload file
- Store file in a temp area
- Create a model object (i.e. database row) to represent the file and say the state is "processing".
- Fire up a django-q job to ingest the file, giving it the filename
- Return a view to this model.
- The async job loads the file, parses the relevant aspects to json, stores the data in the model object (i.e. in the database), marks the model state as "ready".
- The user can reload the page to see the data (or use websockets etc to tell it to reload).